# ASP.Net MVC 5 HttpStatusCode for Child action & ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developping a small ActionFilter that redirect to a maintenance page with HTTP 503 status code when my site will go offline and I'm wondering is this piece of code useful for Ajax & Child actions?

```
var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

I'm following this blog post:
http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/take-your-asp-net-mvc-application-offline-via-a-global-attribute

Here is the attribute definition and I'm wondering why he doesn't set the response status code for a child action

```
public class OfflineMessageAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
       {
           filterContext.Result = new ContentResult {Content = string.Empty};
       }
       else
       {
           filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
           {
               ViewName = "Offline"
           };
           var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
           response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
           response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: useful in what context ? What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: If I return a classic View in the response I will add the Http 503 status code. Is this required for Ajax & Child action.

Comment: **Is this required for Ajax & Child action ?** You tell us. How do we know your requirements ?

Comment: I've update the post

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Child actions will be typically accessed from another (main) view. So when the user requests that view(via the corresponding action method), this action filter will be executed and the `filterContext.IsChildAction` will return `false` and the code in the `else` condition will be executed. that means user will get the Offline view/page. The code in question is setting the status code in the else part.

Even if there is a child action call in the original view/action method user requested, they won't see it because they will be getting the Offline view, not the view they requested ,hence the child action call is not even executed!.

If the Offline view has a child action(*which i doubt!*), `filterContext.IsChildAction` will return `true` and the response for the child action call will be an empty string. So empty string will be injected to the place in Offline view wherever the child action call is made.

Now if someone tries to directly access the action method used for child action,  When that request comes the `filterContext.IsChildAction` will return `true` and user will get Offline page.

Comment: Very clear answer. In case of an ajax call, should I set a 503 status code? Thanks

Comment: The current code will take care of requests coming from an Ajax call as well.